# Beeswarm boxplot plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, data-analysis

Currently I am studying statistics. I depicted the data using a beeswarm chart (picture below).[image]

Next I want to combine the box chart with beeswarm.
I use the command `boxplot(pcs ~ homeless, data = osteo, add = T)` (I use R language). Then my wish is that the result should be like the image below.

[image: Beswarm boxplot]

But now I am facing an error: **"Error in xypolygon(xx, yy, lty = "blank", col = boxfill[i]): plot.new has not been called yet"**. This error appears when I enter `add=T` parameter for boxplot.

[image]

In the process of waiting for help from everyone I will try to find more information from google.

Thank you and Best Regards

Comment: Plot. new tries to make a new object from a point plot. I don't think you made a standard point plot, i.e. (xm,ym). This displays the plot window. Run your command in that window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand your comment. Here is my dataset. I only work on 2 column pcs and homeless.
https://www3.amherst.edu/~nhorton/r2/datasets/helpmiss.csv
Could you please help me to check?

Comment: Hello @Rfatic-san, This issue is solved. Thank you for your feedback